# Easyphp phpmyadmin password does not work for new user

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, easyphp

Ok so I am using easyphp 12.1 and phpmyadmin 3.5.3 and mysql 5.5.27.
The problem is that every time I create a user with a password using either coomadline or using phpmyadmin user interface, the password of the created in the database 'user' in mysql shows a random password and not the one I set and I cant access mysql as the created user in coomandline using the password I have set.

Comment: When you say it shows as 'random' are you meaning it displays the hash value? What query are you running to create the user? FYI: Passwords should *never* be stored on the database in a plain text format. Seeing the hash is a good thing!

Comment: Well is this is a hash value "*02CA878DEEBAABB98FEBEC2B9B6473AD0AFAC9E7" ? I used the query "CREATE USER kuu IDENTIFIED BY 'moo';". I mean this is supposed to create a user called kuu with password 'moo' right? But when I try to log in as kuu and provide the password moo, they say that access is denied but when I try to log in without providing the password, they let me in. Very weird problem I got here.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//adding-users.html

Take a read through that guide and try to follow the commands step for step. I'm not extremely well versed in MySQL access but I've had similar issues before which are caused by users belonging to the wrong domain. So while you may have a 'kuu' user that is assigned locally to the database a user 'kuu' authenticating from a remote address may be denied.

If you were to run the query as:

```
CREATE USER 'kuu'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'moo';
```

...then you'd be allowed to authenticate anywhere. Next obviously you'd want to provide privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'kuu'@'%' with GRANT OPTION;
```

If those don't work then I think we would need to know more details about your setup and other things you've done up until now on the database.

PS. The string of characters you see is a hash. If you're interested in learning more about them, Look at hashing algorithms on google like AES, old ones like MD5 or even play around with a hash generator: http://quickhash.com/

Comment: Thanks for the
 reply, I will surely take your advice for consideration and will approve this advice after testing it.